# How can I connect the ANT+ SDK and Flutter Blue Plus to the Wahoo TICKRfit watch to retrieve data from the watch?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, helper, watch

I am new to Flutter and currently facing the issue of how I can connect the ANT+ SDK and Flutter Blue Plus to the Wahoo TICKRfit watch to retrieve data from the watch?
Can I ask if anyone in the community has worked on this before? Please enlighten me and guide me through any errors.

I tried , but cant find solve my issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.